is that possible to check current managed package version name on post install script
When upgrading managed package, i need to check current pacakage version name contains BPM then i need to remove picklist values using post install script. how to check current pacakage version name?
if(context.isUpgrade()) {
        
}


In a word: no. Your code cannot access the version name. Regardless, the version number should be enough - you must be doing something a bit unusual.

You can use System.requestVersion, which returns the version of your package. See the Version class for more details.
if (System.requestVersion() == new Version(1,0))
{
    // Do something
}
if ((System.requestVersion().major() == 1) 
     && (System.requestVersion().minor() > 0)
     && (System.requestVersion().minor() <=9))
{
    // Do something different for versions 1.1 to 1.9
}
else if (System.requestVersion().compareTo(new Version(2,0)) >= 0)
{
    // Do something completely different for versions 2.0 or greater
}


Hi @Tushar Jadav
Thanks for your response
i dont want to check versions
i  want to check version name. based on version name i  need to remove pick values from object.
eg. my version name is : June_2024_5 and another version name June_2024_5_BPM.  i need to if version contains BPM then remove values.

The version name is not available. Note that the suggested approach never includes the patch version value, in my experience, and that this causes an uncatchable exception if called outside a managed package which breaks the ability to run the code on a scratch org while doing package development. See this idea for more details.

The VersionName of a managed package isn't directly accessible via Apex. You might consider a workaround by setting a custom metadata or custom setting in your package with the version name. Then, in your post-install script, you can query this custom setting or metadata to get the version name and perform actions based on whether it contains "BPM".

Hi @phil W,
Thanks for your response. It make sense.
we are going to have two versions on each
release,in one versions we dont want some picklist values. in that how we can achieve any suggestions, or may be can we check odd or even version. if minor version then remove values

@Tushar Jadav
Yes we can have custom setting but after package upload each time we need to add version name records on custom metadata. is that possible to trigger after package upload create version name  as record on custom metadata?

Why have two versions of each release? Why not track this using feature management and ensure that only relevant customers have the required feature enabled?

Hi @Phil W,
Our case we have picklist value on user object say role for our managed
package, in some subscriber org we have picklist added that we need to remove, based on picklist value we are handling using apex.

So track if the feature is enabled on the org and remove the values that shouldn't be there. Having two separate versions of the same package feels like an entirely wrong approach. If you are talking about sometimes having extensions to your package, or not, then actually put those extras into a separately installed package that extends your core package.
